# Need Help Regarding Regular Expression in TCL

Tags: regex, tcl

Can Anyone help me "Execution flow" of the follwing Regular Expression in TCL.

```
% regexp {^([01]?[0-9][0-9]?|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$} 9
1 (success)
%
%
% regexp {^([01]?[0-9][0-9]?|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$} 64
1 (success)
% regexp {^([01]?[0-9][0-9]?|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$} 255
1 (success)
% regexp {^([01]?[0-9][0-9]?|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$} 256
0 (Fail)
% regexp {^([01]?[0-9][0-9]?|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$} 1000
0 (Fail)
```

Can Anyone Please Explain me how these are executing ? I am struggling to understand .

Answer (score 6):

The regexp first has the anchors `^` and `$` around the main capturing group indicated by brackets here `([01]?[0-9][0-9]?|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])` which means that it is checking the whole string.

Second, inside the capture group, we have 3 parts:

`[01]?[0-9][0-9]?`

`2[0-4][0-9]`

`25[0-5]`

They are separated with `|` (or) operators, which means if the string satisfies any of the 3 parts, the match succeeds.

Now, to the individual parts:

1. `[01]?[0-9][0-9]?` This means that it matches 0 or 1 times [01] (either 0 or 1), then any digit, and again any digit, if there's one. Together, this accepts strings like `000` or `199` but nothing above 199.
2. `2[0-4][0-9]` this follows the same logic as above, except that it validates strings with numbers from 200 to 249.
3. `25[0-5]` Finally, this one validates strings with numbers from 250 to 255.

Since there's nothing more, only numbers ranging from `000` to `255` will succeed in the validation.

This is why 9, 64 and 255 passed, but not 256 or 1000.

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer to the question, just exploring other ways to do this validation:

```
proc from_0_to_255 {n} {
    expr {[string is integer -strict $n] && 0 <= $n && $n <= 255}
}
from_0_to_255 256          ; # => 0
```

```
proc int_in_range {n {from 0} {to 255}} {
    expr {[string is integer -strict $n] && $from <= $n && $n <= $to}
}
int_in_range 256           ; # => 0
int_in_range 256  0 1024   ; # => 1
```

```
proc int_in_range {n args} {
    array set range [list -from 0 -to 255 {*}$args]
    expr {
        [string is integer -strict $n] &&
        $range(-from) <= $n && $n <= $range(-to)
    }
}
int_in_range 256           ; # => 0
int_in_range 256 -to 1024  ; # => 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Everything is detailled in http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions.

```
^        Match the beginning of the line
$        Match the end of the line (or before newline at the end)
?        Match 1 or 0 times
|        Alternation
()       Grouping
[]       Bracketed Character class
```

Comment: A better link would have been http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm (it's the equivalent resource for Tcl) though the RE languages are the same over the subset used in the question.

Answer (score 0):

It matches to the following numbers

```
[01]?[0-9][0-9]? -> 0 - 9, 00 - 99, 000 - 199
2[0-4][0-9]      -> 200 - 249
25[0-5]          -> 250 - 255
```